# Adding a custom kernel Module to android OS

Tags: android, background-application

I am working on a Project for which I have to create a module which can capture the user actions(like touch coordinates, pressure applied, touch area etc.,). I need to implement this at the kernel level because I should be able to access the data across applications.[I have read that, we cannot collect user interactions and other related information that is not generated by our app.So I want a method/ module which will be monitoring all the applications.]

To put it simple, I have to design a method/module which can read the data collected by the sensors when the user uses the phone.

Can anyone help me with possible solutions for this?

[EDIT]
After a discussion with my guide, I am required to add a background app for android rather than creating a custom kernel, because  there are so many problems in implementing the custom kernels on a large scale....

Comment: This means you can only capture from users using your modified kernel, which means they have to install your custom Android ROM (or the kernel) for this.

Comment: Yes, i will be deploying this kernel in some Aakash tablets for the testing purpose.

Comment: The kernel is not necessary the best place to do this, as the information you want is probably amongst that already exposed.  You might try `adb shell getevent` on an *unmodified* device - though you'd need to modify the security model to read that information from an *app* on the device.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Are you talking about the background app thing in android?

Comment: I wasn't, as you added that later, but the basic idea applies.  Your difficulty in doing this from an app will be lack of permission for an app to access the raw input devices.  You will need to modify the device (change the node permissions) or its security model (ie, "root" it and use a helper process such as `getevent` itself run via your root shim) if you want to work around that.

Comment: Hello friends, i will also do the same thing. I am at beginning, can you help me please for the first step ? where do i have to start to do this ? did u achieve this ? @avnkailash